# Keypress warning - use the new keyword if hiding was intended

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I keep getting the following error message at `void KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`:

> Warning 'SpeedyRent.Form2.KeyPress(object,
>   System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)' hides inherited member
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.KeyPress'. Use the new keyword if hiding
>   was intended.

This is my code so far:

```
void KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

with the following 3 references:

```
this.totalTxt.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPress);
this.remainTxt.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPress);
this.paidTxt.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPress);
```

What is causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is named `KeyPress`, but the there is already an event named [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherited from `Control`. Try using a name that won't conflict with any inherited members, like this:

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Also note, you can bind your events like this:

```
this.totalTxt.KeyPress += this.TextBox_KeyPress;
this.remainTxt.KeyPress += this.TextBox_KeyPress;
this.paidTxt.KeyPress += this.TextBox_KeyPress;
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is causing it?

You're declaring a method with the same name as an event declared in a base class. That *hides* the event within the derived class, which isn't a good idea in general.

Two options:

- Use `new` as the compiler suggests
- Just rename the method

Personally I'd take the latter approach, giving the method a name which actually says what it does:

```
private void SuppressNonDigits(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

You can also subscribe using rather less verbose syntax than before, with method group conversions:

```
totalTxt.KeyPress += SuppressNonDigits;
remainTxt.KeyPress += SuppressNonDigits;
paidTxt.KeyPress += SuppressNonDigits;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever class you have this method (`KeyPress`) in inherits from a class that has a non-`virtual` `KeyPress` method already.

Comment: Not a method in this case, but an event.